# Which .cma file corresponds with which module in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

If I'm programming in the OCaml toploop and I want to use a package from the [OCaml standard library](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/) or [some other library](http://www.janestreet.com/ocaml/doc/core/index.html), how I can find out which .cma file to load? In the standard library for example, `String` is in `str.cma` and `Big_int` is in `nums.cma`, so the filenames are not discernible from the module name or description.

Is there an easy way to look up the correct file for a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Po' Lazarus suggested, I used `ocamlobjinfo` to construct a mapping between the `.cma` files and the modules defined for easy reference.

- `bigarray.cma`:

  - BigArray
- `dbm.cma`:

  - Dbm
- `dynlink.cma`:

  - Dynlinkaux
  - Dynlink
- `graphics.cma`:

  - Graphics
  - GraphicsX11
- `nums.cma`:

  - Int_misc
  - Nat
  - Big_int
  - Arith_flags
  - Ratio
  - Num
  - Arith_status
- `stdlib.cma`

  - Pervasives
  - Array
  - List
  - Char
  - String
  - Sys
  - Hashtbl
  - Sort
  - Marshal
  - Obj
  - Int32
  - Int64
  - Nativeint
  - Lexing
  - Parsing
  - Set
  - Map
  - Stack
  - Queue
  - CamlinternalLazy
  - Lazy
  - Stream
  - Buffer
  - Printf
  - Format
  - Scanf
  - Arg
  - Printexc
  - Gc
  - Digest
  - Random
  - Callback
  - CamlinternalOO
  - Oo
  - CamlinternalMod
  - Genlex
  - Weak
  - Filename
  - Complex
  - ArrayLabels
  - ListLabels
  - StringLabels
  - MoreLabels
  - StdLabels
- `str.cma`:

  - Str
- `toplevellib.cma`:

  - Misc
  - Tbl
  - Config
  - Clflags
  - Terminfo
  - Ccomp
  - Warnings
  - Consistbl
  - Linenum
  - Location
  - Longident
  - Syntaxerr
  - Parser
  - Lexer
  - Parse
  - Printast
  - Unused_var
  - Ident
  - Path
  - Primitive
  - Types
  - Btype
  - Oprint
  - Subst
  - Predef
  - Datarepr
  - Env
  - Typedtree
  - Ctype
  - Printtyp
  - Includeclass
  - Mtype
  - Includecore
  - Includemod
  - Parmatch
  - Typetexp
  - Stypes
  - Typecore
  - Typedecl
  - Typeclass
  - Typemod
  - Lambda
  - Printlambda
  - Typeopt
  - Switch
  - Matching
  - Translobj
  - Translcore
  - Translclass
  - Translmod
  - Simplif
  - Runtimedef
  - Meta
  - Instruct
  - Bytegen
  - Printinstr
  - Opcodes
  - Emitcode
  - Bytesections
  - Dll
  - Symtable
  - Bytelink
  - Bytelibrarian
  - Bytepackager
  - Pparse
  - Errors
  - Compile
  - Main_args
  - Genprintval
  - Toploop
  - Trace
  - Topdirs
  - Topmain
- `unix.cma`:

  - Unix
  - UnixLabels

Comment: I considered reversing the mapping, with modules in alphabetical order, but this arrangement provides a clear view of which modules are separated into which files while still allowing readers to CTRL-F the module they need.

Answer (score 6):

Typically, given an Ocaml library `.cma` you can get the modules it defines using `objinfo` (a.k.a. `ocamlobjinfo` notably on Debian, Ubuntu, …). So, given library paths (/usr/lib/ocaml etc.) and time to spend, it should be possible to construct a mapping between modules and Ocaml library.

Comment: Thanks for the remainder, I had forgotten about this tool. It's called `objinfo` in the OCaml distribution, but packaged as `ocamlobjinfo` by Debian.

Comment: Yep, I did forget that, but they should have called it `objdump` to be more non-specific ^^

Comment: reverse search is easier and doesn't depend on extra tools :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used `ocamlobjinfo` to construct a mapping like you suggested.

Answer (score 4):

First, you don't really want to know which cma to load, rather you want to know which package to load via ocamlfind. Next thing to notice is that ocaml compilers need to perform the same thing to compile the project - i.e. by the name of the module referenced in source code find the compiled interface for that module. So let's emulate that behaviour. Compilers get the include paths from command-line, but we have to search all possible include paths. So here we go :

```
for i in $(ocamlfind list | cut -d ' ' -f 1) ; do
  if [ -r $(ocamlfind query $i)/XXX.cmi ] ; then
    echo $i; break;
  fi ;
done
```

or

```
ocamlfind printconf path | xargs -n1 -I/ find / -name XXX.cmi
```

NB the mapping from module name to filename is not unique - e.g. `SomeModule` can be represented either by `someModule.cmi` or `SomeModule.cmi` (less common).

Comment: It does suppose that every module you're interested in are Findlib-compatible (ie with a meta file), which is mostly the case, and that the meta file is well correct and complete, which is sometimes wishful thinking...

Comment: Neither solution depends on correct META at all :) And the second solution uses ocamlfind only to detect reasonable include paths. But in either way it is XXI already and broken ocamlfind packages should be fixed (and guilty parties punished with maximum severity!), not workarounded.

Comment: Yep! you right on both counts... cmi files should be there with the module name, but it's quite complicated to get the name you full qualified name of a module, with packed modules (try that on ocamlgraph for instance).

Answer (score 2):

`String` (the usual functions on the `string` datatype) is not in `str.cma`, it's `Str` (functions for manipulation regular expressions) that is.

There is a similar rationale for the `nums.cma` name: it mostly encapsulates the module `Num` which is a layer on top of different "big numbers" libraries (`Nat`, `Big_int`, `Ratio`). Note that nowadays you may want to use [Zarith](http://forge.ocamlcore.org/projects/zarith) instead.

Comment: Useful comment, but not an answer really (explaining -1).

Answer (score 1):

I never noticed this problem, but you're right that you can't tell anything from the name of the module.  Since I usually have to read the documentation first, I've always just gotten the info from the [docs](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/index.html) (listed at the beginning of each section for the standard modules).

A suaver solution is to use GODI and its associated [`findlib`](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/findlib.html) mechanism, which looks like it solves this problem and many others.  In particular, it scales beyond just the modules that come with the OCaml distribution.

Comment: I have nothing against GODI (ok almost nothing), but Findlib can be used without GODI too...